# Removing attributes from New Cart Price Rule - Actions tab

Tags: product-attribute, shopping-cart-price-rules

At New Cart Price Rule -> Action Tab. There is a green plus mark, where I can choose Conditions. The problem is, that I see there all added attributes to Magento but I need only few. Is there a way to remove not necessary attributes from that list?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you just need to set the attributes to not be used in promotions, just set **Use for Promo Rule Conditions** to *No*.

Comment: Thank You, it worked.

Comment: You are most welcome :)